# Is something like SiteLock necessary if you're using Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: security, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, xss, sitelock

I've used Google App Engine in the past and I know they offer a ton of features for web security as listed at https://cloud.google.com/security/. These include things like SSL/TLS, encrypted databases, and Cloud Security Scanner for XSS and other forms of injections.

I feel like if you are going with a giant platform like GCP or AWS, you don't need third party stuff like SiteLock, which sounds like it's more for people on hosting services like Hostgator, Hostmonster, GoDaddy, etc.

Is this hypothesis accurate?

Answer (score -1):

Well if your hosting platform provides you with the security tools you need, then you dont need to consider third part security tools.

If you want more control over the security of your VM instance or you want to have an understanding of the security processes, then you can setup open source security tools on your VM.

Comment: does not answer the question. does GCP have or doesn't have what is being asked? else its not a valid answer.